# Can "hence" be used instead of "after"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms, contemporary-english

Can "hence" be used instead of "after"?

Dictionaries say that "hence" is the same as "in the future". Some usage suggest otherwise.

Example:

A man who died in 1945 proved himself relevant, 120 years after.

A man who died in 1945 proved himself relevant, 120 years hence.

Comment: I don't think so. *Hence* means from now, not some point in the past.

Comment: _Thence_ can mean from some distal point in time, but is archaic in this usage. 'Later' is the idiomatic choice. // Your examples are strange.

Comment: The Beatles, who were famous in the 1960s, will still be famous 200 years hence.

Comment: @Mick: Probably. But as you yourself point out, the assertion is that The Beatles will still be famous in 2216, not 2160.

Comment: Hence means "from now", it's that simple.  The second sentence means 120 years from now; the first sentence is meaningless and missing some more words.

Comment: I am really curious to know what made you ask this question and what research you've done before asking it. Are you just interested in learning *how to use the word hence*?

Comment: @Rathony I am writing about Jose Rizal. He died on 1896.

Answer (score -3):

You've kind of answered your own question.  The second version of your statement is a perfect usage of hence.

Hence doesn't have to mean, in the future from now, but in the future of the events you've been speaking of so far.

Comment: Not so: subsequence to future or past events is spoken of with *thence*.

Comment: I disagree, and if you tried to put thence into his sentence it would sound strange.  Your argument suggests that hence should never have been used in a history.  Another example: "The town was founded in 1890, but 50 years hence a dam was built, flooding the town."

Comment: No "hence" means "from now".  simple.

Comment: Shakespeare begs to differ. http://www.shakespeareswords.com/hence-thence-and-whence

Comment: @MBurke Which of those Shakespearean uses do you think does not mean "from **the current** time/place?"